# Applying NFC in Java: any existing API or libraries?

Tags: java, netbeans, nfc

I have a project which will apply NFC technology. I will be using Java as programming language and Netbeans IDE to do it. 
It seems that NFC is rather a new technology and there doesn't seems to be many references I can get on the web yet. I would like to ask whether anyone know any existing API or libraries or even any other easier way that I can make use of to apply the NFC technology in my project. I might be using NFC tag to store ID and get the ID from the tag as input.

Comment: You are looking for android right?

Comment: I am using java to program it. I am using a computer and considering buying NFC devices, not using mobile phone.

Comment: @Amigos : did you find any solution? or made the java app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some resources:

1. [NFC Tools for Java](https://github.com/grundid/nfctools)
2. [NDEF Tools for Android](https://code.google.com/p/ndef-tools-for-android/)
3. [NFC Eclipse plugin](https://code.google.com/p/nfc-eclipse-plugin/) (NDEF Editor)
4. [Open NFC](http://www.open-nfc.org/)

I realize you've tagged this question with netbeans, but at least you know what you're missing on the eclipse link there. I've written 2 and 3 and also contributed to 1.

Answer (score 1):

The [ST25 Software Development Kit](http://www.st.com/st25sdk) is a Java development kit that includes a library useable on Android and Windows/Linux PCs. It supports all tags that follow ISO and NFC Forum protocols as well as proprietary features from ST25 tag IC Series.

Disclaimer: I am on the development team for the ST25 SDK.

Comment: Hi @Damien, if I may ask a question on different subject, I was looking for some implementation in your android SDK of read/write protection for your ST25TA or ST25DV tags... does this exist?

Comment: @agenis Yes, this is possible to do. Better to ask a separate question though :)

Comment: good! here's my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67594927/nfc-tag-password-protection-with-st25-android-sdk   ;-)