# NFC-tag password protection with ST25 android SDK

Tags: android, nfc, password-protection, st25

I'm working with **ST25 tags**, more specifically type5 tags ST25DV64K. The ST25 SDK for android has some interesting examples and tutorials in it. I'm still struggling to use the code example provided at the end of the doc [here](https://www.st.com/resource/en/user_manual/dm00445390-st25-software-development-kit-stmicroelectronics.pdf) concerning **password-protected data**, which consist in those lines:

```
byte[] password;
int passwordNumber = type5Tag.getPasswordNumber(area);
tag.presentPassword(passwordNumber, password);
NDEFMsg ndefMsg = myTag.readNdefMessage(area);
```

first problem, when I instanciate a type5 tag i don't see those methods for `Type5Tag` class:

```
import com.st.st25sdk.type5.*;
Type5Tag tag5;
tag5.??
```

Then, it is not clear how we are supposed to set up a password in the first place. I can't find any examples of setting up a password for a specific area, and removing it, and what is the format of the password that we can use? Is it possible to do this from android or do we have to use the ST25 app? Examples welcome! Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the ST25 SDK Zip file, you will find an example of a basic Android App using the ST25 SDK Library (it is in \integration\android\examples\ST25AndroidDemoApp).

This example uses a class called “TagDiscovery” which is able to identify any ST25 Tag and to instantiate the right object. In your case, if you are only using ST25DV64K Tags, you will probably want to do something simple.

Here is what I suggest you:
In your android activity, I expect that you have subscribed to receive a notification every time an NFC tag is taped (in “ST25AndroidDemoApp” example, look at enableForegroundDispatch() in onResume() function).
To identify if the Intent corresponds to an “NFC Intent”, we check if the Intent’s Action is ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED, or ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED or ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.

When this is the case, we know that it is an NFC Intent. We can then call this to get the instance of androidTag:

```
Tag androidTag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
```

This object represents the current NFC tag in Android.

We’re now going to instantiate a ST25DVTag object.

```
import com.st.st25sdk.type5.st25dv.ST25DVTag;

…

AndroidReaderInterface readerInterface = AndroidReaderInterface.newInstance(androidTag);
byte[] uid = androidTag.getId();
uid = Helper.reverseByteArray(uid);
ST25DVTag myST25DVTag = new ST25DVTag(readerInterface, uid);
```

You now have an object called myST25DVTag that can be used to communicate with the tag!

For example, if you want to use the passwords:

```
byte[] password = new byte[];      // TODO: Fill the password
int passwordNumber = myST25DVTag.getPasswordNumber(area);
myST25DVTag.presentPassword(passwordNumber, password);
NDEFMsg ndefMsg = myST25DVTag.readNdefMessage(area);
```

Before doing that, you need to check which password is associated to this area. The tag has 3 passwords that can be freely assigned to any area. By default no password is set so you should set one. Here is an example where I use the password 2 for Area1:

```
int AREA1 = 1;
int passwordChosen = 2;
myST25DVTag.setPasswordNumber(AREA1, passwordChosen);
```

I suggest that you install the ”ST25 NFC Tap” Android App from Google Play: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.st.st25nfc&hl=fr&gl=US
If you tap you ST25DV and go to the “Areas Security Status” menu, you will be able to see: the number of areas, which ones are protected by password for read and/or write, which password is used…etc

If you are interested, the source code of this application is available here: https://www.st.com/en/embedded-software/stsw-st25001.html

Tell me if something is unclear.

Disclaimer: I am on of the development team for the ST25 SDK.

Comment: I would not recommend using `enableForegroundDispatch()` with setting a password or reading/writing to a tag with a password set on it unless you need support for API's lower than API 19 as `enableForegroundDispatch()` will generates lots of errors when used by real users. It is much better to use `enableReaderMode()` instead as you get to correctly prompt the user with sound when you have actually finished interacting with the Tag.

Comment: NFC Tags can trig some native processing. Ex: open an URL , do a Bluetooth pairing, send a SMS…etc.
enableForegroundDispatch() allows your Activity to take the hand over this native processing. In other words, it means: “give the NFC Intent to the current activity instead of executing the native processing”. This is done only when the Activity is in foreground (that's why it is important to call disableForegroundDispatch() in onPause() ).
It empowers the application to decide what should be done of NFC Intents. What kind of errors did you experience with enableForegroundDispatch() ?

Comment: `enableForegroundDispatch()` generates a lot of `TagLostException` or `IOException` if you are doing anything that is not cached `ndef` reading. The system NFC service/App reads the card and makes a notification sound, packages up any data in to an `Intent`, and then has to `pause` and `resume` you app to deliver the `Intent`, you then have to process the `Intent` in the App and by the time you have done this the user has moved the card out of the RF fields because they take the Notification sound as success. If you have to do you own reading or writing then the card is not in range.

Comment: Another reason to use `enableReaderMode()` instead of `enableForegroundDispatch()` again if you are doing anything more than cached `ndef` reading, is that most other  `Tag` operations state "This is an I/O operation and will block until complete. It must not be called from the main application thread", `onNewIntent` is run in the main application thread so you should create your own thread to process the NFC Intent (most people don't) whereas `enableReaderMode` automatically runs `onTagDiscovered` in a new thread.

Comment: We have not experienced the problems that you mention. Our applications receive the NFC Intent and then all the NFC processing are done through the transceive() function. That's right that they should not be done in the UI Thread so we are using an ASYNC Task.

Comment: @OlivierGrenoble - In NFC tap app by STM, we are not able to set any of the passwords. Also, the writing of chosen password also fails.

Comment: I assume that you are using a ST25DV tag  I suggest that you log a question on:. https://community.st.com/s/topic/0TO0X000000BSrjWAG/st25-dynamic-nfc-tags-st25dv-series