# how to read data from a web UI and share using NFC card

Tags: java, nfc

I am new to NFC ,what we  want is that we have a web page where we   have all user details like Name, Email, Facebook URL, Linked in URL and is stored in a database. Now my question is is it possible that an NFC card or any app can read that data and share using the NFC card.

Please bear with my question and may be wrong .

Comment: You can get the data from a website. The difficult part is the NFC card. You need hardware that works with your software. Take a look at this post that show's a list of NFC APIs for Java: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15874506

Comment: Thanks ,see what i want  is that details which i have in my database the NFC card can read ,do we have any other language apart from java and can i use any app for testing.Lets say i have name,email and facebook and i want the NFC card to read it and when person taps that info on anyones mobile it passess.Thanks in advance

Comment: NFC is very hardware dependant, you don't say what platform you want to do this and you don't say what Tag hardware you are wanting to use as "the NFC card".

Comment: we will get the blank cards and get them printed using printer machine

Comment: There are many different types of NFC card, some are less suitable than others, I would recommend that you don't do anything with Mifare Classic cards as they are non standard and less compatible. But still don't have and idea of what hardware you want to use to transfer the data from the web page/database to the NFC Card.

Comment: Thanks Andrew ,my target is that i am creating a UI where i will have all the user details Like name,Email,facebook URL,Instagram URL,Linked URL.My end objective is that these details should be transferred/read by NFC card and later that user can Tap those details in any phone and they can be shared.Let me know if it makes sense

Comment: @NS009 If it doesn't need to be Java I would use a a NodeMCU (=Arduino with WiFi) with an RFID module. (Programming in C++) So you have access to the web page and can communicate via NFC. If you need the data transferred to a PC or other device you can use a serial connection (USB) and establish a communication with the host programmed in eg. Java.

Answer (score 0):

**Web NFC** allows you to read and write NFC tags on Chrome for Android.

To write a simple text record, pass a string to the `NDEFReader` `write()` method.

```js
const ndef = new NDEFReader();
await ndef.write("Hello World");
```

Scannibg nearby NFC tags is pretty easy as well:

```js
const ndef = new NDEFReader();
await ndef.scan();

ndef.addEventListener("reading", ({ message, serialNumber }) => {
  console.log(`> Serial Number: ${serialNumber}`);
  console.log(`> Records: (${message.records.length})`);
});
```

I'd recommend you read https://web.dev/nfc and play with https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/web-nfc/ to see if that's what you're looking for.

In your specific case, I'd store data in a JSON format and read them later:

```js
const encoder = new TextEncoder();
const data = {
  firstname: "François",
  lastname: "Beaufort"
};
const jsonRecord = {
  recordType: "mime",
  mediaType: "application/json",
  data: encoder.encode(JSON.stringify(data))
};

const ndef = new NDEFReader();
await ndef.write({ records: [jsonRecord] });
```

```js
// Scan NFC tags and go trough |message.records|. 
// Once you have a record, check its |mediaType| and read |data|.
if (record.mediaType === "application/json") {
  const textDecoder = new TextDecoder();
  console.log(`JSON: ${JSON.parse(decoder.decode(record.data))}`);
}
```